# How to count items in list view without returning the items?

Tags: list-view-threshold

I get the view limit exception when I make a request to the SharePoint online api that has more than 5K items in the view. I want to be able to count the number of items in the view without returning those items (thereby bypassing the exception).

Here is the ViewXml template that I use:

<View>
  <RowLimit>1000</RowLimit>
  <Query>
    <Where>
      <And>
        <Geq>
          <FieldRef Name="{2}"></FieldRef>
          <Value Type="DateTime">{0:yyyy-MM-dd}</Value>
        </Geq>
        <Leq>
          <FieldRef Name="{2}"></FieldRef>
          <Value Type="DateTime">{1:yyyy-MM-dd}</Value>
        </Leq>
      </And>
    </Where>
  </Query>
</View>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is "no". There is no way to check for the number of items returned by a `View`. There is [`List.ItemCount`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee537421%28v=office.15%29) but it will return the number of items in the list. Unfiltered.

If you need the number of items returned by the `View` you'll need to get the items and count them. Use "paging" to get around the 5K-Limit.

- You can use `RowLimit` in the CAML, to stay below 5K
- [`CamlQuery`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee536390%28v%3Doffice.15%29), as well as [`ListItemCollection`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee537431%28v%3Doffice.15%29) has a `ListItemCollectionPosition` which is null when all items are read..

... so you'd need something along the lines of:

```
$list = Get-MyCoolList
$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
$query.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where>...</Where></Query><RowLimit>4999</RowLimit></View>";
do {
  $items = $list.GetItems($query);
  $query.ListItemCollectionPosition = $items.ListItemCollectionPosition;

  #  ... do cool stuff...

} while ($query.ListItemCollectionPosition -ne $null)
```

Comment: I use a Row Limit of 1,000  actually but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: So, how do you access SharePoint? REST?

Comment: I use the CSOM. I just can't seem to figure out why I'm getting the view limit.

Answer (score 0):

When the list contains more than 5000 items, the columns you are querying must be indexed.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1076854/Overcoming-the-List-View-Threshold-in-SharePoint-C

This solves my problem, but doesn't answer my original question. I would still like to know if there is a way to get the count without having to download all the rows.

Comment: Ah. I didn't see that coming. Views are simply a "filter". If your list contains more than 5000 items, you have to build a query/view that a) uses only indexed columns to do the filtering and b) returns less than 5000 items.